# Local development - can't buld hello_world

Tags: solana-program

I was having issues building another project so I tried the hello_world guide here:

https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/local

and here

https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/rust

When I ran `cargo build-bpf`, I got a bunch of errors like this:

```
   Compiling bincode v1.3.3
error[E0658]: deriving `Default` on enums is experimental
  --> src/nonce/state/current.rs:70:17
   |
70 | #[derive(Debug, Default, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #86985 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86985> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(derive_default_enum)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0658]: deriving `Default` on enums is experimental
  --> src/stake/state.rs:19:17
   |
19 | #[derive(Debug, Default, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Clone, Copy, AbiExample)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #86985 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86985> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(derive_default_enum)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
```

Here are the versions of stuff:

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
bpf

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
```

```
solana-cli 1.13.8 (src:43daa379; feat:1775889670)
```

These are the versions that were installed using the `stable` solana installation and the given rust installation command

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

I saw another post about using rustc 1.65 and that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the setup that currently works for me:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- rustc 1.69.0-nightly
- solana-cli 1.14.10
- bpf-tools v1.29

Downloading the `1.14.10` release for testnet and devnet should make your build work. You're probably trying to run on localnet or devnet, but 1.13.8 is a mainnet release.

You can check a list of the releases [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases?page=1).

Comment: Thank you very much!