# error: package `winnow v0.4.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-spl

When trying to run "anchor build" I get this error. I noticed I can run other programs but it seems as soon as i implement the anchor-spl crate i run into this problem. I've tried updating anchor, rustc, and solana cli as well as trying different versions of each. I've uninstalled all three and reinstalled them as well. I've tried `rustup install nightly` then `rustup default nightly` as well as someone on another similar post suggested.

when checking my versions this is what i get.

````
rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)```

but then when running ```anchor build``` this is what's returned

```error: package `winnow v0.4.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev``` how do i update the rustc version that anchor is seeing?
````

Comment: I've personally found that a lot of solana releases are broken. 

You might find [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/local-development-cant-buld-hello-world/6525?noredirect=1#comment5350_6525) helpful. 

Solana-cli 1.14.10 works for building anchor 0.27.0 with anchor-spl 0.27.0 in my setup

Comment: I get this error too using seahorse-cli and seahorse-py when building spl programs in python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is misleading because the error actually results from the version of rustc that ships with solana and not your system's rustc version. See https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31428

To fix this error, use the latest version of `anchor-spl` from git by adding it to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
anchor-spl = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor" }
```

If you are still getting the same error, you might have to run `cargo clean` and remove `Cargo.lock`.

**Note**

The `winnow` dependency comes from `spl-token-2022` crate that `anchor-spl` depends on but neither of those crates are the actual problem. The main problem is that the latest release of solana(1.14.17) is using an outdated version of rustc. This means MSRV problems like this one will go away once a new Solana release is published.

Related: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/31418

Comment: Adding your temporary fix for anyone that might want to do something similar.
I ran into this problem from other libraries, aside from `anchor-spl`.

Acheron's temporary fix for `anchor-spl` was to fix the `winnow` version in your project's `Cargo.toml`, ie. `winnow = "=0.4.1"`.
This should only be temporary until MSRV issues are resolved by a later Solana release.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2478/files

Answer (score 3):

I just added `winnow="0.4.1"` in dependency section of `Cargo.toml` file and it worked.

- Initially I have added `anchor-spl = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor" }` in place of `anchor-spl = "0.27.0"`.
- Then i just remained `anchor-spl = "0.27.0"` and added `winnow="0.4.1"` and it's working.
- You can also try this may be it works in your case.

Comment: Hi, could you post your whole Cargo.toml file? I tried to add the `winnow` as you suggested but it still doesn't work - the issue remains exactly the same, this `winnow` dependency seems to be ignored. My dependencies section looks like this:
`[dependencies] anchor-lang = "0.27.0" anchor-spl = "0.27.0" winnow = "0.4.1"` (cannot insert new lines here, sorry)

Comment: Ok, looks like it needs to be `winnow = "=0.4.1"` instead as suggested above by Joe and it works correctly