# Error when anchor build - package `toml_datetime v0.6.2` cannot be built

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, cargo

I'm trying to build using anchor but there seems to be this error

```
error: package `toml_datetime v0.6.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

This is my current dependencies in cargo.toml file

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.26.0"
mpl-token-metadata = { version="1.9.0", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
spl-token-2022 = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"], optional = true }
spl-associated-token-account = { version = "1.1.1", features = ["no-entrypoint"], optional = true }
anchor-spl = "0.26.0"
```

My environment
solana: solana-cli 1.15.2
rustc: rustc 1.69.0
anchor: anchor-cli 0.27.0
cargo: cargo 1.69.0

Things I've tried:

- Adding `winnow = "=0.4.1"` to cargo.toml
- changing solana-cli version to 1.14.10 and 1.14.18

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to use the latest version of `anchor-spl` from GitHub, you can achieve this by adding the following line to your `Cargo.toml`.

```
anchor-spl = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor" }
```

See https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6535/471 for more information on why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

cargo build-sbf -- --ignore-rust-version

Comment: Can you expand on the answer? The command is good, but just add some text describing what it does and why it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I don't really remember where did I found the answer it was almost a year ago!. But remember that it was due to two different build-... I have line with sbf. Unfortunately I don't have time to search all over again.  Because of -1 for reputation I even regret that I post this one. Thank you.

Comment: Here I’ve modded you back up to zero if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact error for a while today until I stumbled on this GitHub issue. This is the exact configuration that resolved it for me.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2511#issuecomment-1580958263

anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.27.0

solana --version
solana-cli 1.14.17

rustc --version
rustc 1.70.0