# error: package toml_datetime v0.6.2 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, rust

I have been scouring my issue all over the internet and stack exchange but nothing that I have found works.

I am using Anchor to manage my Solana programs but keep getting the error:

`` error: package `toml_datetime v0.6.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev ``

I have updated Rust and set the default version bu using:

`rustup default 1.69.0 or rustup default stable`

`rustup default`

And get the output result:

`1.69.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)`

The current toml file is:

```
[package]
name = "mint-nft"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "mint_nft"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.26.0"
anchor-spl = "0.26.0"
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "1.11.2", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
```

I am at a loss why the compiler is saying that my version is 1.62.0-dev when the current version is 1.69.0.

I have tried variations of anchor versions up to 0.28.0 but to no avail.

Does anybody have an idea of how to go about this and get the program to compile?  Note that I am running Debian 11 on bare metal (no VM).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is about your `solana-cli` version, not Anchor version.

You can update to `1.16.0` with `solana-install init 1.16.0` and this will be fixed.

> I have been scouring my issue all over the internet and stack exchange but nothing that I have found works.

[This](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/error-package-winnow-v0-4-4-cannot-be-built-because-it-requires-rustc-1-64-0) is the first place you'd see this error on the internet and the [accepted answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6535/471) explains why this error happens.

Comment: This was a major part of the solution as well as the next response below.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Upgrade your rust version to the latest one
- Upgrade your Solana CLI version to 1.16.0
- Upgrade your Anchor CLI version to 0.28.0
- Run `cargo update -p solana-zk-token-sdk --precise 1.14.18`
- Run `anchor build`

Comment: The cargo update command helped after doing the answer above.  Thank you, I was able to get my program compiled and working.

Comment: Very good! can you mark my answer as verified so that other developers can also get help when they meet the same issue. ;)