# Error when anchor build - package `constant_time_eq v0.3.0` cannot be built

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, cargo

I'm trying to build using anchor but there seems to be this error

```
error: package `constant_time_eq v0.3.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.66.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

This is my current dependencies in cargo.toml file.

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.27.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor" }
bytemuck = "1.13.1"
toml_datetime = "=0.6.1"
constant_time_eq = "0.3.0"
winnow = "=0.4.1"
solana-program = "=1.14.17"
```

solana-cli version is 1.14.20.
rustc version 1.70.0
anchor-cli version is 0.27.0

I also have tried to

- downgrade to solana 1.14.17
- fix anchor-spl according to the https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6535/471 guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from the post you've linked:

> The error message is misleading because the error actually results from the version of rustc that ships with solana and not your system's rustc version

> The main problem is that the latest release of solana(1.14.17) is using an outdated version of rustc. This means MSRV problems like this one will go away once a new Solana release is published.

Solana 1.16 release uses a newer version of rustc, you can upgrade to solve your problem by running:

`solana-install init 1.16.0`

There is also no need for the extra dependencies in `Cargo.toml` after the upgrade:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = "0.28.0"
```

Comment: Solana cli version upgrade to the 1.16 is working.
Seems like your analysis for the solana release rustc version is correct.

It works even I didn't update the anchor-lang version to 0.28

Great thanks, @acheron

Comment: So I can upgrade to 1.16, but then I wont be able to test as Invoked an instruction with data that is too large. is there a middle ground?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, after upgrading the version of Solana, the `anchor build` is working
But in testing, there is an error.

```
'Program CAyJyJA5aKy62Uiq7JTRpnpRXdniGzVoeq7Qsamo1Kf8 invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Initialize',
    'Program CAyJyJA5aKy62Uiq7JTRpnpRXdniGzVoeq7Qsamo1Kf8 consumed 8489 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933804 > 1280)',
    'Program CAyJyJA5aKy62Uiq7JTRpnpRXdniGzVoeq7Qsamo1Kf8 failed: Program failed to complete'
```

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Oura, getting the same issue? did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to use anchor 0.26 with solana 1.14 and encountering this error.
Try updating Anchor.toml with the following:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.26.0"
blake3 = "=1.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix by installing Solana's latest release:

```
solana-install init 1.16.6
```

And also anchor's latest version:

```
avm install 0.28.0
```

Comment: So i was able to find a fix by installing solana's latest release `solana-install init 1.16.6` and also anchor's latest version `avm install 0.28.0`