# 'Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933932 > 1280)', Getting this error

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transactions, account, solana-cli

I'm getting this error

```
 Program logged: "Instruction: CreateVester"
> Program consumed: 5565 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: "Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933932 > 1280)"
> Program returned error: "Program failed to complete"
```

and this is the instruction

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateVester<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 1392, seeds = [VESTERSEED], bump)]
    pub vester: AccountLoader<'info, Vester>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

```
  pub fn create_vester(ctx:Context<CreateVester>) -> Result<()>{
        ctx.accounts.vester.load_init()?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

I am using solana version `1.16.4`, I tried to switch to `1.14.20`, but there i can't compile the program cause of these type of random errors

```
error: package `winnow v0.4.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

And i can't deploy with `1.16.4`, deployment always fails, some people said switch to `1.14.20` but i can't use `anchor test` cause of the Given errors.

This type of account creaqtion were previously, and somehow they are not working now

I get [this](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4LwNqvZJosWLGx5BLu5o19FX9PT2XXN3PqU2hUZgSFtNvFkxZz1bKv2VkWHeRwvE9ABbcyg6TkMUrpe9abifXtmr?cluster=devnet) type of errors in other txs where account creation is done.

Same thing happend [HERE](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/7078/1174) after the said fixes

I tried [This](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31960) fix as well, down graded to `1.14.18`, then i get dependencies error

```
 package `winnow v0.5.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

these are the dependencies

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.25.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.25.0"}
borsh = {version = "0.9", features = ["const-generics"]}
mpl-token-metadata = {version = "1.3.2", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}
solana-program = {version = "1.9.29"}
streamflow-sdk = {version = "0.6.2", features = ["cpi"]}
```

Comment: can you show us all your dependencies in Cargo.toml?

Comment: Just updated the question now

Comment: you can try pinning these incompatible dependencies to a common version by adding `winnow="=0.4.1"
toml_datetime="=0.6.1"`